# How to disable emoji shortcut in all apps

Tags: macos, keyboard, emoji

I wanna off emojis which open by shortcut (usually this is control+option+space) in all of my apps.

Sometimes this open by others hotkeys at the wrong time and i wanna off this.

There may be a terminal command to make it?..

[image]

Comment: See the linked QA - just change the shortcut to a 'junk' combination you will never hit by accident & doesn't conflict with anything else. I use things like Cmd/Ctrl/Opt/Shift/F19 when I never want to trigger something.

Comment: @Tetsujin thats great idea, but i cant find this combination in settings..

Comment: You have to make it, per the instructions in the linked answer.